# Disabling button client-side if page is valid

Tags: javascript, asp.net, validation

I'd like to disable an 'Upload' button if the page is valid in javascript.

The button itself causes validation, and there's a mix of validators (required field validators, regex validators etc.).

Any ideas??

Comment: Where are you stuck? Seems like a simple rquirement.

Comment: I'm stuck on where I would code the disabling of the button. The clientclick event (where I'd ideally like to code the disabling of the button) is fired before the validators.

Comment: Judging by your lack of response I'm guessing this isn't such a 'simple requirement'. I don't see the point in people making (or up-voting) such comments, be constructive instead? It'd only take you a minute to post a helpful response if it really is such a simple requirement.

Comment: Sorry Daniel I did not visit this question after you poseted your comment. I was busy with some office work. Where are you stuck? Also means... Post some code/other stuff which you tried so that it wil be easier for people to help you. Hope you got what I meant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only solution I've found here is to scrap the ASP validators and implement my own big custom javascript validation on the clientclick events.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, i've had that issue before.  As the page is posting back to the server, just disable the button altoghether:

```
document.getElementById("button").disabled = true;
```

Or hide it:

```
document.getElementById("button").style.display = "none";
```

And then they can't click on it again.

Comment: No not necessarily everytime I trigger the validation, just every time the page is valid when the 'Upload' button is clicked. The problem that I have here is that there is an upload button - who's server-side click event takes a few moments to execute. Meaning the user has the chance to click the button again, so they're uploading many copies of the same file if they keep clicking. I need to stop this, but obviously don't want to do so if the upload is not valid (because when they've 'made it valid' by amending the textbox's on the form they can then not click the button).

Comment: Oh you don't mean page is valid, you essentially want to prevent duplicate clicks of the button.  I updated my response above.

Comment: Thanks mate, the code of how to disable/hide the button is not the problem - it's where I put this code. Also - yes, I want to prevent duplicate clicks of the button - but at the same time I must not disable the button every time, because if the page is not valid (and then the user amends the fields to make them valid) they then need to click the button.